# Removing GitHub tools on termux?

Tags: shell, android, termux

I don't know if i can ask this question here or not. I have cloned some tools from GitHub on my termux. Then i ran the bash file "install.sh" that was a customized login with password tool. This is the [link](https://github.com/htr-tech/termux-login.git)
So now i want to delete it and make my login back to default. I did search it but i didn't find the answer. Last time , i deleted my termux data to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Where should i ask this ?

Comment: And that's why you don't run random shell scripts (or other programs) without having some understanding of what they do, and if you can trust the source. The [install.sh in question](https://github.com/htr-tech/termux-login/blob/master/install.sh) is even obfuscated so you can't easily tell what it does!

Comment: And the python file is not source code but bytecode.

Comment: @A.B Oh damn, I didn't even notice that! I'd stay far away from this repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the 'eval' to 'echo' in the script spits out this code (after removing echo statements):

```
apt update
apt install python -y
apt install ruby -y
gem install lolcat
rm $PREFIX/etc/bash.bashrc
cd core
cp bash.bashrc $PREFIX/etc
cp login_script.py $PREFIX/etc
```

You can just undo what it did.

**Removing the gem install**

```
$ gem uninstal lolcat
```

**remove the two files copied**

```
$ rm $PREFIX/etc/bash.bashrc
$ rm $PREFIX/etc/login_script.py
```

Now type 'exit' & restart Termux and see if things are back to normal.

For future reference, maybe try not to install scripts like this unless you look over them first.  The source for this script looks like trash.

Hope that helps,
Jim

Comment: Thanks but when i did this , i couldn't find the "core" folder. So i could not finish what you said. Now instead of default ~ sign before $ sign , it shows bash-5.2$  idk why. Anyway thank you.

Comment: The core folder isn't important.  The two copy commands after are what matters.  The copy to `$PREFIX/etc/bash.bashrc`.  Anyway, it looks like you blew away /etc/bash.bashrc.  Use your package manager to reinstall bash.

Comment: The bash file show the python byte code here: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/login_script.py.  Delete this file.  I'd clear the cache and data in termux and then delete it and reinstall.  If you used a package manager to install bash, reinstall it.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's all is true and works for me.